# Switching views with page control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I am making an app in iphone and i want my views to change just like we do (swipe) in page control, I am wondering is there any way to use page control for the required functionality? or what could be the alternative?

Regards
MGD

Comment: read UIPageVontroll, UIScrollView and UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible.

There is a sample project from Apple: **PageControl**

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl

Comment: thanks for help, its an ipad example with a very different functionality that i require, u can take a look urself i mean its just we click on page and it displays a view, but i need to implement "swipe" switching of views with page control or any other alternative

Answer (score 1):

You can use uiscrollview with horizontal scrolling. You need to put the next view in place when the scroll view detects that the user has swiped enough to display the next view. I can give you more details if you update your question with more details, like will the views take up full screen or you want it to be like a coverflow effect.